# High-side current monitor to measure microamps

Tags: current-measurement, differential-amplifier

I am trying to sense very low current (50 - 200 μA)  on the high side of a circuit, and was considering [LTC6102HV](http://cds.linear.com/docs/Datasheet/6102fd.pdf) for the job since it can be "floated" to 105 V.

My problem, however, is that my circuit is not floated to +105 V but to -105 V and the current does not flow to the ground. If I understand it right, I cannot use the LTC6102HV.

Here's a picture that illustrates the problem, I am trying to measure I<sub>sense</sub> through R<sub>sense</sub>.

[image]

I can probably just use a diff amp (e.g. [AD629](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD629.pdf)), but since I am measuring microamps, I am not sure if it is the right way to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt if I can give you an answer, but you'll probably need to know what's the highest value Rsense your application will allow (or maximum voltage drop across Rsense), and how accurately (and how precisely) do you need to measure the current.

Comment: The Highest value of R_sense will depend on what I choose to use to measure the current.  I can see different possibilities, there are a gazillion differential opamps and  a few highside current monitors. It's just that I am not sure what to use. Most highside current monitors I have come across does not really have "high" negative voltages as inputs.  And I have not seen any applications with diff amp that measures microamps. I have seen people measuring miliamps. And as far as precision goes, it has to be quite precise I am afraid, since it is a very low current.

Comment: In that case, you could use, say, 25 kOhms for Rsense and then use any voltage sensor able to measure 0-5 V. You can float the whole circuit at ~-100V, and isolate the communication back to whatever circuit needs the information back at the ground level.

Comment: Please don't post large images. Olin scaled it down to less than 1/10th of the original size and it's still more than large enough.

Comment: Sorry about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the AD629 you already found should work for you. If you look at the [web page for it](http://www.analog.com/en/specialty-amplifiers/current-sense-amplifiers/ad629/products/product.html) you will see that it is categorized under 'Current Sense Amplifiers'. Its special feature making it so usable is the capability to amplify correctly even with high common mode voltages. This means that both inputs have a voltage with respect to ground, but only a small difference. This is exactly what you need for a current sense amplifier.

When you measure micro amps, the current sense resistor you want to use might be about 1kOhm, which would give you 1mV/1µA (without amplification). You might want to look at [Dave Jones uCurrent project](http://www.alternatezone.com/electronics/ucurrent/) as an example for how to measure even nano amps, and for a discussion of how the size of the sense resistor might affect your circuit (though I doubt that even 1V voltage drop will affect your circuit when it is powered by 100V...)

Another option you can consider is using a isolated OpAmp like the [AMC1200](http://www.ti.com/product/amc1200). You would need to power directly from the rail where you are measuring, so you have no common mode voltage. The isolated output allows you to use it at any other place of your circuit without any level shifting.

Comment: Thank you, I have been leaning towards AD629, since the common mode voltage for it can be +- 260V.  The Isolation OpAmp AMC1200 is an interesting solution too.

Answer (score 0):

ground is relative. The LTC6102 can be used if you connect V+ to ground and v- to -105V. In a floating power application, the chip just wants to see the correct potential across V+ to v-.

Now of-course this means that "ground" will be at -105V! So You will need an isolation circuit to connect to the low voltage zero ground referenced digital side.

Answer (score 0):

The current sense limits of the AD629 seem to be dictated by the relationship between the shunt resistance and the common mode error produced at the output of the difference amplifier. This is shown below in Table 5 from the AD629 datasheet.

[image: AD629 Common mode error vs shunt resistance]

The effect of this relationship is that the current you are attempting to sense must be smaller in magnitude than the "Error Indicated(mA)" current in Table 5 above. **Lowering** the sense resistor value may be a way to reduce the common mode error on the output until the output SNR is limited by the 15μVpp noise voltage on the output. This means that a 1Ω resistor may be the shunt resistance you are looking for while trying to measure a 100-200μVpp signal, assuming you need to fully reject common mode interference.

In simulation, it looks like detecting DC level shifts with a higher value 1kΩ shunt resistor actually works, although some of the common mode signal gets into the measurement. This may be acceptable for your applications. Special attention to that common mode signal will be necessary if it shares the same bandwidth as the 50-200μVpp differential signal you're trying to measure.